# JavaFX: Custom TableViewSelectionModel

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a TableView which lists several addresses as a preview. The selected address can be edited in a form next to the TableView. In case that the user has made changes to the selected address and changes the selected address in the TableView, I want to ask him if he wants to proceed without saving changes. If no, I want the Tableview to stay at the currently selected position, if the user wants to discard the changes the TableView may perform the selection change.

My approach would have been to extend the SelectionModel of the TableView and only allow the selection to change if the user answers the described dialog or there are no changes. Basically I only want to add an if-clause before changing the selection in the Tableview. Unfortunately, I only found the abstract class “TableViewSelectionModel” and no concrete implementations of it.

Is there any way to obtain this desired behavior without implementing the whole class?

Comment: There's no concrete implementation in the public API. Your best bet is going to be to define a wrapper class subclassing `TableSelectionModel`. Pass in the default instance of the selection model you get from the table view, and delegate the method calls to it if you want selection to change. There are quite a lot of methods to write, but each one becomes pretty trivial if you implement it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with James_D's recommendation:

```
public class ControllableTableSelectionModel<T> extends TableViewSelectionModel<T>{

    private TableViewSelectionModel<T> originalModel;
    private ControlsTableView controller;

    public ControllableTableSelectionModel(TableViewSelectionModel<T> originalModel, ControlsTableView controller) {
        super(originalModel.getTableView());
        this.originalModel=originalModel;
        this.controller=controller;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumnBase<T, ?> column) {
        return originalModel.isSelected(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.selectLeftCell();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectRightCell() {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.selectRightCell();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAboveCell() {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.selectAboveCell();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void selectBelowCell() {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.selectBelowCell();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void selectRange(int minRow, TableColumnBase<T, ?> minColumn, int maxRow,
            TableColumnBase<T, ?> maxColumn) {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.selectRange(minRow, minColumn, maxRow, maxColumn);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected int getItemCount() {
        return originalModel.getTableView().getItems().size();
    }

    @Override
    protected T getModelItem(int index) {
        return originalModel.getTableView().getItems().get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void focus(int index) {
        originalModel.getTableView().getFocusModel().focus(index);      
    }

    @Override
    public int getFocusedIndex() {
        return originalModel.getTableView().getFocusModel().getFocusedIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TablePosition> getSelectedCells() {
        return originalModel.getSelectedCells();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        return originalModel.isSelected(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.select(row, column);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.clearAndSelect(row, column);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        if(controller.canSelect(this))
        {
            originalModel.clearSelection(row, column);
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: A note on this: I had a a TableViewSelectionModel very similar to this and it was working fine on Oracle JDK 8, Liberica JDK 8, 13, and 15 with JavaFX included and I think a few others. Then I tried it on Temurin JDK 11 with JavaFX SDK 11 from openJFX as a separate library and suddenly my table items became un-selectable. My suspicion is that its due to the final methods defined in TableViewSelectionModel which could not be overridden. So be aware, this solution may be dependent on your JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an improvement to your self-answer by making it more generic and applying the *"tell, don't ask!"* principle:

```
public class ControllableTableSelectionModel<T> extends TableViewSelectionModel<T> {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface VetoableSelectAction{
        void execute();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SelectionVeto {
      <T>  void allow(TableViewSelectionModel<T> tableViewSelectionModel, SelectionVeto vetoableSelectAction);
    }

    private final TableViewSelectionModel<T> originalModel;
    private final SelectionVeto selectionVeto;

    public ControllableTableSelectionModel(TableViewSelectionModel<T> originalModel, SelectionVeto selectionVeto) {
        super(originalModel.getTableView());
        this.originalModel = originalModel;
        this.selectionVeto = selectionVeto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumnBase<T, ?> column) {
        return originalModel.isSelected(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {
        selectionVeto.allow(this, () -> originalModel.selectLeftCell());
    }
    // ...
}
```

I personally have no use for the second parameter in `allow()`:

```
public class ControllableTableSelectionModel<T> extends TableViewSelectionModel<T> {
    // ...
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SelectionVeto{
       void allow(VetoableSelectAction vetoableSelectAction);
    }
    // ...
    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {
        selectionVeto.allow(() -> originalModel.selectLeftCell());
    }
    // ...
}
```